# Do not allow undocking from AdvDockPanel

Tags: delphi, toolbar, tms

I'm using components from TMS and I'd like to know how to allow AdvToolBar to dock into AdvDockPanels without allowing it to undock and then appearing like a solo Form.

I'm looking for an option like:

`DockMode := [dmCannotFloat];`

Comment: This is possible using Jedi JVCL JvDocking. Also, obviously, possible in Toolbar2000 + SpTBX.

Comment: Allright thanks. I currently have SpTBX components, but I'm considering moving to TMS components because SpTBX are no longer upgrading their compos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event EndMove of TAdvCustomToolBar I add those lines to make it act like the Property AutoDockOnClose and that does just what I want. AllowFloating is set to True.

```
{$IFDEF CHALAM}
   if (Assigned(FLastDock)) then
   begin
      self.Parent := FLastDock;
      if FFloatingWindow <> nil then
      begin
         FFloatingWindow.Free;
         FFloatingWindow := nil;
      end;
   end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 1):

So far it's not possible. You could set `AllowFloating` to false but then you can only move the toolbar in the current DockPanel